# How can I build a dataTable, with a dropbox filter on top, calculated on backend?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, datatables

I need to change a dataTable to add a dropbox on top of it (not in the header) to filter it.

I have this column with dates like dd/mm/yyyy and I the year range does not go from 01/01/N to 31/12/N. It goes from 01/11/N to 31/10/N+1 and this rule will be used to calculate the filters available.

In case I have only this to lines :

```
 -------------------------------------------------------
|   date_header  |  header 2  |  header 3  |  header 4  |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
|   01/05/2013   |     abc    |     qwe    |     xyz    |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
|   05/11/2018   |     hdf    |     ydb    |     lot    |
 -------------------------------------------------------
```

I should get the following results on de dropbox (respecting the rule I talked about) :

<2012/2013>
and
<2018/2019>

So, firstly, I need this dropbox to read every values presents on this column and calculate the filter values.
And then, filter the table using the range selected.

-- EDIT1 --

This is my initilialization script:

```
$element.DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": this._tableDatasource,
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "sDom": 'ltipr',
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "paging": this._detautNombreElementsPerPage > 0,
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "iDisplayLength": this._detautNombreElementsPerPage,
    "order": [[ this._defautColumnTrie, this._defautTypeTrie ]],
    "columns": this._columns,
    "columnDefs" : this._columnsProperties,
    "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        if ($(nRow).hasClass('even')) {
            $(nRow).addClass("alt");
        } else {
            if ($(nRow).hasClass('alt')) {
                $(nRow).removeClass("alt");
            }
        }
    },
    "fnDrawCallback": function() {
        var pageCount = Math.ceil((this.fnSettings().fnRecordsDisplay()) / this.fnSettings()._iDisplayLength);

        if (pageCount > 1)  {
            $('.dataTables_paginate').show(); 
        } else {
            $('.dataTables_paginate').hide(); 
        }
    },
    "language": {       
        "sProcessing":    "Chargement en cours...",
        "sLengthMenu":    "Montrer _MENU_ registres",
        "sZeroRecords":   "Aucun résultat n'a été trouvé",
        "sEmptyTable":    "Aucune donnée disponible pour ce tableau",
        "sInfo":          "_TOTAL_ éléments trouvés, affichage de _START_ à _END_",
        "sInfoEmpty":     "0 éléments trouvés, affichage de 0 à 0",
        "sInfoFiltered":  "(filtré au total de _MAX_ registres)",
        "sInfoPostFix":   "",
        "sSearch":        "Chercher:",
        "sUrl":           "",
        "sInfoThousands":  ",",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Chargement en cours...",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    "Première page",
            "sLast":    "Dernière page",
            "sNext":    "Page suivante",
            "sPrevious": "Page précédente"
        }
    },
    "initComplete": function() {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == "tableIndisponibilitesPassees") {
            var dates = $('#tableIndisponibilitesPassees tr td:first-child').toArray();

            populate_dropdown(dates);

            //$('#tableIndisponibilitesPassees').dataTable().fnClearTable();

       //$('#tableIndisponibilitesPassees').dataTable().fnFilter("20/10/2015 08:00:00").draw();

            set_handler();
        }
    }
});
```

I had to add the initComplete to populate the table.

This is my populate dropdown :

```
function populate_dropdown(dates) {
    // make an empty array variable to hold the list of saisons
    var saisons = [];

    // loop through the dates
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {

        var year = Number($(dates[i]).html().split(' ')[0].split('/')[2]);
        var month = Number($(dates[i]).html().split(' ')[0].split('/')[1] - 1);
        var day = Number($(dates[i]).html().split(' ')[0].split('/')[0]);
        var datePFHA = new Date(year, month, day);

        var dateDebutSaison = new Date(year, 10, 1);

        // now let's calculate the season
        var saison;
        if (datePFHA < dateDebutSaison) {
            saison = Number(year-1) + "/" + year;
        } else {
            saison = year + "/" + Number(year+1);
        }

        // now let's add that saison to the seasons array (if it's not already in the array!)
        if ($.inArray(saison, saisons) == -1) {
            saisons.push(saison);
        }
    }

    // now that we're done looping through and building the seasons list, let's sort the array
    saisons.sort();

    // make a variable to hold all the <option> fields for the select dropdown
    var options = "";

    // loop through the years and make the options fields
    $.each(saisons, function(key,value) {
        options += "<option> Saison " + value + "</option>";
    }); 

    // take the new options string that we've built and put it inside the <select> dropdown
    $('#filtre_saison').append(options);
}
```

And now I'm trying to set the handler like this :

```
function set_handler(dataTable) {
    console.log("set_handler");
    var filtre = $('#filtre_saison').on('change', function() {
        // when someone changes the filter, get the beginning and ending of the season
        var yearsSaison = $("#filtre_saison").val().split(' ')[1];
        var debutSaison = new Date(yearsSaison.split('/')[0],10,01);
        var finSaison = new Date(debutSaison.getFullYear() + 1, debutSaison.getMonth(), debutSaison.getDate());

        console.log($('#tableIndisponibilitesPassees'));
        console.log($('#tableIndisponibilitesPassees').dataTable());
     console.log($('#tableIndisponibilitesPassees').dataTable().fnFilter("20/10/2015 08:00:00"));
     console.log($('#tableIndisponibilitesPassees').dataTable().fnFilter("20/10/2015 08:00:00").draw());
        $('#tableIndisponibilitesPassees').dataTable().fnFilter("20/10/2015 08:00:00").draw();
        //$(dataTable).search("20/10/2015 08:00:00").draw();

        //filter_table(debutSaison, finSaison);
    });
}
```

I've tryed the search method on dataTable but it doesn't work. Return an error saying that search is not a function.
I've tryed with the fnFilter but now it returns an error in the draw function saying :

*Cannot read property 'draw' of undefined*

I've checked and after the fnFilter function, is returning undefined.

--- EDIT 2 ---

Almost forgot. This is my html code :

```
<select name="filtre_saison" id="filtre_saison">
</select>
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You haven't posted any code, so it's hard to tell how you're trying to do it (and this site isn't really just for having other people write code for you).

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet because I have no ideas of what I can do. I'm not the one who've built the table so it is a bit complex for me and I'm lacking of ideas. For now I would like some concepts so I can search a bit more about it cause I'm googling for a while and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution :

HTML :

```
<select name="filtre_saison" id="filtre_saison">
</select>

<table>
    ...
</table>
```

Javascript code :

```
"initComplete": function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == "tableBuildings") {
        var dates = $('#tableBuildings tr td:first-child').toArray();

        populate_dropdown(dates);

        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push( function( settings, data, dataIndex, rowData, counter ) {
            if (settings.nTable.id === 'tableBuildings') {

                //Calculation of beggining and ending of the room
                var yearsBuildig = $("#filtre_saison").val().split(' ')[1];
                var initialDate = new Date(yearsBuildig.split('/')[0],10,01);
                var endDate = new Date(initialDate.getFullYear() + 1, initialDate.getMonth(), initialDate.getDate());

                //Calculation of the Date object of the PFHA
                var year = Number(rowData.initialDate.display.split(' ')[0].split('/')[2]);
                var month = Number(rowData.initialDate.display.split(' ')[0].split('/')[1] - 1);
                var day = Number(rowData.initialDate.display.split(' ')[0].split('/')[0]);
                var hours = Number(rowData.initialDate.display.split(' ')[1].split(':')[2]);
                var buildingDate = new Date(year, month, day);

                if (buildingDate >= initialDate && buildingDate < endDate) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    //this row doesn't contain that year, let's hide the whole <tr>
                    return false;
                }

            } else {
                return true;
            }
        });

        $('#filtre_saison').on('change', function() {
            table.draw();
        });

        table.draw();
    }
}

function populate_dropdown(dates) {
    // make an empty array variable to hold the list of building
    var building = [];

    // loop through the dates
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {

        var year = Number($(dates[i]).html().split(' ')[0].split('/')[2]);
        var month = Number($(dates[i]).html().split(' ')[0].split('/')[1] - 1);
        var day = Number($(dates[i]).html().split(' ')[0].split('/')[0]);
        var buildingDate = new Date(year, month, day);

        var initialDateRoom = new Date(year, 10, 1);

        // now let's calculate the room
        var room;
        if (buildingDate < initialDateRoom) {
            room = Number(year-1) + "/" + year;
        } else {
            room = year + "/" + Number(year+1);
        }

        // now let's add that room to the building array (if it's not already in the array!)
        if ($.inArray(room, building) == -1) {
            building.push(room);
        }
    }

    // now that we're done looping through and building the building list, let's sort the array
    building.sort();

    // make a variable to hold all the <option> fields for the select dropdown
    var options = "";

    // loop through the years and make the options fields
    $.each(building, function(key,value) {
        options += "<option> room " + value + "</option>";
    }); 

    // take the new options string that we've built and put it inside the <select> dropdown
    $('#filtre_saison').append(options);
}
```

Just added a function to populate the dropbox in the initComplete property to populate it only after the table is fully initialized (all the row values charged because I need to have different values depending on the values present on first column).
Then, I use the method to build my custom filter and then just redraw the table and Puff!

PS :
Needed to append this if :

```
if (settings.nTable.id === 'tableBuildings')
```

to check if it's the specific table I want because I have multiple tables on this page and the filter is applied to every datatable tables present in the page.

Thankyou @Reverend Pete

Answer (score 0):

OK, without any specifics of how the table is built, etc., a general way to go about this might be to use javascript/jQuery to loop through the `date` fields and build the year list.  Then from that year list, you can populate a dropdown.  Then you add a change handler to the dropdown and use javascript to show/hide elements based on the selected year.

Here's a quick and dirty example, which is assuming a couple things:

1. The  fields that hold the date has a class (in my case, 'date_element')
2. The dates in the fields are of a consistent format

You can run the working snippet below to see it in action.  And I added lots of code comments to explain what certain lines are doing.

Hope it helps!   (and I hope I didn't just do your homework for you...).

```js
// trigger the function that populates the dropdown when the page has finished loading, and then add a change handler on the dropdown
$(document).ready(function() {
  populate_dropdown();
  set_handler();
});

function populate_dropdown() {
  // make an empty array variable to hold the list of years
  var years = [];
  
  // loop through the date_header fields (assuming that the elements have a class of date_element)
  $('.date_element').each(function(){
    // $(this) inside the each function refers to the <td class='date_element'> element
    var this_date = $(this).html();
    // get the year from the date. It would be better to use actual Date functions, but if the 
    // dates are consistent, we can just break them apart on the / characters and grab the last value
    var this_year = Number(this_date.split('/')[2]);
    // now let's add that year to the years array (if it's not already in the array!)
    if ($.inArray(this_year, years) == -1) {
      years.push(this_year)
    }
  });
  
  // now that we're done looping through and building the year list, let's sort the array
  years.sort();
  
  // make a variable to hold all the <option> fields for the select dropdown
  var options = "";
  
  // loop through the years and make the options fields
  $.each(years, function(key,value) {
    options += "<option>" + value + "/" + Number(value+1) + "</option>";
  }); 
  
  // take the new options string that we've built and put it inside the <select> dropdown
  $('#year_filter').append(options)
}


function set_handler() {
  $('#year_filter').change(function() {
    // when someone changes the filter, get the value of the first year
    var selected_year = $("#year_filter").val().split('/')[0];
    // make sure it's a number 
    if (!isNaN(selected_year)) {
      filter_table(selected_year);
    } else {
      show_all_rows();
    }
  });
}

function filter_table(selected_year) {
  //loop through the table rows, show ones that have the year and hide ones that don't have it
  $('.date_element').each(function() {
    if ($(this).html().indexOf(selected_year) == -1) {
      //this row doesn't contain that year, let's hide the whole <tr>
      $(this).parent().hide();
    } else {
      $(this).parent().show()
    }
  });
}

function show_all_rows() {
  $('.date_element').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().show();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="year_filter" name="year_filter"><option>Filter By Year</option></select>
</form>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>date_header</th>
    <th>header 1</th>
    <th>header 2</th>
    <th>header 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='date_element'>01/05/2013</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>qwe</td>
    <td>xyz</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='date_element'>05/11/2018</td>
    <td>hdf</td>
    <td>ydb</td>
    <td>lot</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: Just one clarification, do you think this will work on a paged table based on the datatables plugin? If so, I think this is what I need. Thankyou and you can rest assured that this isn't my homework :)

Comment: So it won't work on a DataTables table the way that I've written it.   (It would only filter the visible page, and so it wouldn't re-paginate the table or anything).  How you handle that depends on whether the DataTables is doing pagination by itself, or whether it is using the serverSide option.  But it's probably easiest to just use DataTables search function.   So maybe just remove `filter_table(selected_year);` and replace it with `table.search(selected_year).draw();` where `table` is a variable set when you instantiated DataTable().  And you can limit which columns are searchable...

Comment: I've added some code. Can you try to help me please? Appreciate it

Comment: So in my example, the `table` is a variable that is defined when you FIRST call `dataTable()`.   So in your case, it would be something like ```table = $element.DataTable(...)```. And then you should be able to do the `table.search(selected_year).draw()`

Comment: Just made a few changes and was able to do what I wanted. Thankyou @Reverend Pete